# PHP post array not completed. Only first element received

Tags: php, html, dynamic, html-table

I need to post array value from dynamic html table to PHP.
Please refer below as example:

```
<!----index.html----->
<script>
function addRow(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
       var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
</script>
<form role="form" action="php_process.php" method="POST">
  <table id="this_table">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="number" id="data_number" name="data_number[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow('this_table');">
  <button type="submit" value="1">Save</button>
</form>


<!----php_process.php---->
<?php
$data_submit = $_POST['btn_submit'];
$data_number = $_POST['data_number'];
if($data_submit){
   var_dump($data_number);
   exit();
}
?>
```

When i submit this form only show first element of the array even I have add multiple rows.

```
Output:
Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

Only first element retrieved.

Kindly, please help me.

I have the same exactly code as above, but not problem. Very weird.

Comment: Im confused. Output makes sense with how code is written. You are typing a 2 into the input and then displaying a 2 in your var dump. What are you expecting the output array to be?

Comment: @Bleach because it is dynamic table. when i added another rows, it should appear all the value for each row. not only first element.

Comment: Where's your insertRow and insertCell methods? It could be you're not setting the 'name' property correctly on your new input elements but we can't see that code or the rendered html to check it's correct

Comment: @TommyBs — Built into the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Comment: When I run this, it errors with *Uncaught ReferenceError: rowCount is not defined*. Assuming you can actually see the new cells appearing:  Please provide a real [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin sorry. i have edit my code.

Comment: Is that definitely the only code you have in php_process.php? Have you tried just putting `var_dump($POST)` in there?

Comment: After fixing the name of the submit button, I can't reproduce the problem. I get `array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }` as the output.

Comment: Why are you using [tag:table] when it says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG"?

Comment: @Quentin sorry. amended.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this button

```
 <button type="submit" value="1">Save</button>
```

with this one

```
<button type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="1">Save</button>
```

if you have already define this name to other submit button in this page then change this name and also check data_number this name they should not be duplicate in same page

Comment: Because the coding above is example, in my real coding, the name of button exactly as u suggest, so that is not the issue.

And no other variables using the same name. 

And look at output, it correctly show the data from that array, but only 1st element retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

So the javascript code you provided doesn't work. However the following amendments do make it work.

I've set a rowCount variable and colCount uses the zero index not 1 as you are trying to get the cell length for a row that doesn't exist hence there is no innerHTML when creating a new element. If you did need to use [1] because you have extra rows in your actual table, then please show us the actual relevant code so we can help

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<!----index.html----->
<script>
function addRow(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
       var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
</script>
<form role="form" action="php_process.php" method="POST">
  <table id="this_table">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="number" id="data_number" name="data_number[]"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow('this_table');">
  <button type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="1">Save</button>
</form>
```

I've tested this and it works

Comment: Yes this is exactly my code. I have amended on question. sorry. wrongly post the wrong code. And when post, output only 1st element.

Comment: As it stands my code works and i've tested it. So there's something else you're not showing us. I suspect it might be the fact that you're not showing us your actual code but showing us a subset.

Comment: hm.. something wrong somewhere. As stated, only this page got this issue, i have another page, with exactly same code, but no issue. need to digging where the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote whoever that was for downvoting code that works and was actually different to the code the OP originally posted and not even leaving a comment